# Python dicts: Key apparently not found even though it clearly exists

Tags: python

Okay, I have to be missing something really obvious here. I have this code:

```python
if (field_ref in choices) or (field['id'] in choices) or (field['name'] in choices):
    print(field_ref, field['id'], field['name'], choices)
    kwargs.update(choice_aliases=choices.get(field_ref, choices.get(field['id'], choices[field['name']])))
```

I get a `KeyError` on the `choices[field['name']]` part. The output of the `print` statement is:

```
('organization_type', 1953522, u'What type of organization are you?',
 {
  'organization_type': {'as_club': 3272046, 'other': 3272049, 'as_program_office': 3272045, 'wwu_department': 3272047, 'student': 3272048}, 
  'products_requested': {'handbills': 3268398, 'other': 3268405, 'table_tents': 3268404, 'posters': 3268397, 'banners': 3268399, 't_shirts': 3268401, 'digital_signage': 3268400, 'brochures': 3268403, 'invitations': 3268402}
 }
)
```

(the reason the output is a tuple is because this is Python 2.7). As you can see, the value of `field_ref` is `'organization_type'`, and the same value `'organization_type'` is in the `choices` dictionary, and the `if` statement evaluates to `True` because we're inside it, so clearly at least one of the three statements should be guaranteed to work. What gives?

If it matters, the specific error is

```
KeyError: u'What type of organization are you?'
```

which is the value of `field['name']`.

EDIT: I caught the slow; `choices[field['name']]` is evaluated when the line is parsed instead of after the other two `.get()`s have failed to find anything and are returning their default value, like I was thinking. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, the key is `"What type of organization are you?"`.

And in the dictionary `choices` there is no pair with key equal to "What type of organization are you?". That's the problem.

Comment: You're not technically wrong. I now see the problem; for some reason I was thinking that `choices[field['name']]` would only be evaluated once the other two `.get()`s were tried and failed; I now notice that's not at all the case and feel very silly. I'll just change that last one to `.get(field['name'], {})` and that'll solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave out the `if` and just depend on `.get` for picking which of the values to use:

```
kwargs.update(choice_aliases=choices.get(field_ref, choices.get(field['id'], choices.get(field['name']))))
```

If none of those keys exist in choices, the value given to `choice_aliases=` would be `None`.

If you don't want the `None` value in the kwargs then test for `None` like this:

```
tmp = choices.get(field_ref, choices.get(field['id'], choices.get(field['name'])))
if tmp is not None:
   kwargs.update(choice_aliases=tmp)
```

Comment: I suppose that's not a bad idea. The main reason was that I didn't really want the keyword in the dictionary if it wasn't already there but I don't think it really matters in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the 'if' logic it does not guarantee field['name'] is in choices due to all logic checks being an 'or'.  If all conditions need to be met than change the 'or' to 'and'.  My guess is, you will not satisfy the check.

Comment: No, they don't all need to be met. Just one of them. The `.get()`s will choose one of the existing ones by preference.